# Get error "mismatched input 'as' expecting FROM near ')' in from clause" when run sql query Hadoop Java

Tags: java, sql, hadoop

I created two tables from java code `tableHiveCell` and `tableHiveWiFi`.

When I try to run followed sql command:

```
select count(UEs.cnc) as 'Active UEs' 
                      ^
from 
(select distinct cnc from tableHiveCell wifi  
  union 
 select distinct cnc from tableHiveCell cell)
 as UEs;
```

I get an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException:
Query returned non-zero code: 11,
cause: FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:22 mismatched input 'as' expecting FROM near ')' in from clause
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189).
```

Did I miss something?

**[EDIT 1]**

I tried:

```
select count(UEs.cnc) as 'Active UEs' 
                      ^
from 
(select distinct cnc from tableHiveCell wifi)  
  union 
 (select distinct cnc from tableHiveCell cell)
 as UEs;
```

Same error

**[EDIT 2]**

I tried:

```
select count(UEs.cnc) as Active_UEs
 from (select distinct cnc from tableHiveCell wifi
  union ALL 
 select distinct cnc from tableHiveCell cell) as UEs;
                                              ^
```

Get the same error but last `as`:

```
 line 1:142 mismatched input 'as' expecting Identifier near ')' in subquery source
```

Comment: could you try removing the "as" keyword and simply stating the alias as "Active Ues" and "UEs" without the AS keyword? some sql implementations simply dont have that as thing ( MS?)

Comment: When I run `select count(cnc) as boo from tableHiveCell` it works, don't think its `as` problem. Thanks

Comment: well, then the single string `'` could be your problem  try double quotes :-)

Comment: @Najzero, please see EDIT 2

Comment: Well had a look here ( http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hive/language_manual/joins.html ) and now I think you need to skip the "as" from the alias of your subquery - https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-12/querying-data also uses only "mt" after the subquery to set the alias

Comment: @Najzero, thanks mate, I removed `as` and ';' and now its works, thanks. Please, post your answer to let me vote up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As requested in Answer form:
Hadoop seems to have problems with aliases via `AS` keyword on subqueries and you can easily assign the alias without the `AS` Keyword.

Example can be found here: https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-12/querying-data

And quoted for future visitors ( see `mt` alias for subquery ):

```
SELECT station, year, AVG(max_temperature)
FROM (
  SELECT station, year, MAX(temperature) AS max_temperature
  FROM records2
  WHERE temperature != 9999
    AND (quality = 0 OR quality = 1 OR quality = 4 OR quality = 5 OR quality = 9)
  GROUP BY station, year
) mt
GROUP BY station, year;
```